# How to cover gap in roof?

Tags: wood, roof, construction, roofing, building

I am facing an issue regarding my roof design. there is a gap in the roof that i am worried if I just cover with wood water might go inside.

Here is the final desired results:
[image]

This is the gap that I have issue with now , it's because there is no wall in the center so I can cover it.
[image]

This is how walls that will carry wood looks like :
[image]

**What is the best way to cover this gap ?**

Comment: Is that literally how it was built, open to the air? One would expect it glazed, to provide light to the inner rooms. What's your rainfall expectancy - that looks a pretty shallow pitch to me.

Comment: @Tetsujin not it will be covered with ceiling, and no light can go in, I am also worried that its shallow pitch. left side 2/12 pitch and right is 4/12.. I am thinking to increase them to 3/12, 5/12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "gap" you mean the vertical wall between the top of the roof on the left and the bottom of the roof on the right?

Often times, clerestory windows are put into this kind of vertical wall to provide additional light, but even if you don't use windows, you'd simply treat it as a wall.

Flash it into the lower roof just like you would around a chimney or other roof penetration, put whatever kind of exterior siding on it that's appropriate and fits with the rest of the house, then where the top dies into the roof above, treat it just like you would under any other roof overhang.

If you're using traditional wood clapboards, more modern cement board siding, vinyl siding, etc. It's simple - just build the wall and side it.

If the house is to be brick or stone over traditional wood framing, this becomes a little more tricky, as you have to account for the significant weight of material up there (and build in lintels to support it from below), but you could go with a thin brick/stone veneer which would be reasonably light weight and could probably go on a standard construction with no extra support. You'd have to look at the material you've chosen to see what it would take.